# How to set flag for row except last in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to set flag for each row based on ROW_NUMBER() except last row?

Data Table(events):

```
+-----+-------------+-----------+----------+----------+
| Ref |   E_Date    |   Item    | Customer | Assignee |
+-----+-------------+-----------+----------+----------+
|   1 | 10/10/2017  | Microsoft | DIB      | Jeffry   |
|   2 | 10/11/2017  | Oracle    | UNB      | Asif     |
|   3 | 10/12/2017  | IBM       | UNB      | John     |
|   4 | 10/13/2017  | Microsoft | DIB      | Asif     |
|   5 | 10//14/2017 | Oracle    | UNB      | Jeffry   |
|   6 | 10/15/2017  | SAP       | DIB      | Said     |
|   7 | 10/15/2017  | Microsoft | DIB      | Said     |
+-----+-------------+-----------+----------+----------+
```

Expected result:

```
+-----+------------+-----------+----------+----------+------+
| Ref |   E_Date   |   Item    | Customer | Assignee | Flag |
+-----+------------+-----------+----------+----------+------+
|   1 | 10/10/2017 | Microsoft | DIB      | Jeffry   |    1 |
|   4 | 10/13/2017 | Microsoft | DIB      | Asif     |    1 |
|   7 | 10/15/2017 | Microsoft | DIB      | Said     |    0 |
|   2 | 10/11/2017 | Oracle    | UNB      | Asif     |    1 |
|   5 | 10/14/2017 | Oracle    | UNB      | Jeffry   |    0 |
+-----+------------+-----------+----------+----------+------+
```

My query:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT Ref, E_Date, Item, Customer,Assignee,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Customer, Item) AS cnt,
    CASE WHEN (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Customer, Item ORDER BY Item)) = 1 
    THEN 1   ELSE 0    END Flag
    FROM Events        
) t
WHERE cnt > 1
ORDER BY Item, Customer;
```

Please help me to get result like above expected result

Comment: I don't see the logic in your sample, but you need to understand how `PARTITION BY` works - fiddle with the fields in there

Comment: As your `item/User` is not unique, the "last" row (what ever this means) is random... You should provide sample data in consumable format (no pictures!) fitting to your *expected output*.  Please read [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056)  and [How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Shnugo: Last row of ROW_NUMBER()  to be "0"

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid : Basically i need to set a flag for each rows..   for example if  Row_NUMBER() of an Item/user is 1 and 2 then flag of 1 is "1" and 2 is "0" .....    if Row_Number is 3 , then flag of 1 and 2 is "1" and 3 is "0"

Comment: @SamBinHam There is no implicit order. Each `SELECT WhatEver FROM Events` can return a differently sorted list. Well, this can be the same for 100 calls and one might get the feeling this is fix - but it isn't. Your `ROW_NUMBER` uses only `item` as sort clause. This is not unique, so the result is random... The **last row is senseless without a unqiue sort order**!

Comment: @Shnugo : Thanks for ur update..  So there is any other way to set flag for each item ?

Comment: Please look at the _two_ answers posted and see if they solve your problem

Comment: Make that _three_ answers

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your example, you want to `partition by` item (reset when the item changes) and `order by` ref (decide on rank number based on this)

I don't where your `having` comes into this so took it out

Since you want to identify the *last* record based on this order by, you simply order by  descending.

```
    SELECT Ref, Date, Item, User,
      CASE WHEN (ROW_NUMBER() 
      OVER(PARTITION BY Item ORDER BY ref DESC)) = 1 
      THEN 1 
      ELSE 0 END Flag,
     COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY User, Item) AS cnt
    FROM Events        
    ORDER BY Item, Ref;
```

Answer (score 1):

Give a row number group by `item` and `user` columns in the descending order of `Ref` column. Then set flag as 1 for the row which have row number 1.

**Query**

```
;with cte as (
    select [rn] = row_number() over(
        partition by [item], [user]
        order by [ref] desc
    ), *
    from [your_table_name]
)
select [item], [Ref], [Date], [User],
case [rn] when 1 then 0 else 1 end as [Flag]
from cte
order by [Ref];
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion uses an *updatable CTE* to fetch all rows you want to change. The trick is `TOP 1 WITH TIES`. I use `ROW_NUMBER` directly in the `ORDER BY`. All partitioned row-numbers will get a `1` in the needed rows. All of them are - together! - the `TOP 1` (due to `WITH TIES`).

First I set **all flags = 1** then set the *last row* (defined by `ref`) to zero.

```
DECLARE @mockupTable TABLE(item VARCHAR(100),Ref INT, [Date] DATE, [User] VARCHAR(100), Flag BIT);
INSERT INTO @mockupTable VALUES
 ('Microsoft',101,'2/11/2018','Jeffrey',1)
,('Microsoft',102,'2/14/2018','Joseph',0)
,('IBM',103,'2/11/2018','Arif',1)
,('IBM',104,'2/15/2018','Arif',1)
,('IBM',105,'2/11/2018','Arif',0)
,('Oracle',106,'2/13/2018','Jeffrey',1)
,('Oracle',107,'2/16/2018','Said',1)
,('Oracle',108,'2/12/2018','Joseph',1)
,('Oracle',109,'2/11/2018','Jeffrey',0);

UPDATE @mockupTable SET Flag=1;

WITH UpdatableCTE AS
(SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES Flag
 FROM @mockupTable 
 ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [item] /*,[User] ???*/ ORDER BY [ref] DESC)
)
UPDATE UpdatableCTE SET Flag=0;
```

--At least the result is the same as you've posted above

```
SELECT * FROM @mockupTable;
```

Comment: I have modified my Sample data and Query , Please check now

Comment: @SamBinHam Isn't it one you to Check this? There are three answers with three approaches. Check them and pick the one you like most